# Adding Data to a datagridview in another form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c#-express-2010

Ok, i have 2 forms. form8 contains the datagrid view. the second(form10) form contains a textbox, and a picturebox. This is the code i am trying to use to pass the data, but it will not work.

```
    Form8 frm8;
    public Form10(Form8 frm8): this()
    {
        this.frm8 = frm8;
    }

    private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int n = frm8.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            frm8.dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
            frm8.dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = comboBox1.Text + "|" + textBox3.Text;
            frm8.dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = pictureBox1.Image;
            this.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: U should use a better naming convention

Comment: And remove that empty try/catch all. If you have something wrong in that code, you'll never know.

Comment: @JohnnBlade Currently, what he can't do is to use a worst naming convention :D

Comment: Please tell what exact problem are u facing... any error or exception... try to debug and explain ur problem clearly.

Comment: are you trying to pass the data from one form to another or do you want to display datagrid view row values in textbox....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to refresh the form to get the result.

```
frm8.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
```

or try Application.DoEvents() to get UI thread to refresh.

Comment: +1 for not forcing the good practices instead of fixing his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its better that you create an event coming from Form10, and in form8 you register that event so when you click on the button your data is passed to form8.

You should also do something with your exception log it, and also stick to naming convention to make your code more readable